# I want to Retrieve the Boolean Value From firestore all I want is a syntax from which I can again check the Checkbox getting true value from Firestore

Tags: javascript, java, google-cloud-firestore, boolean, data-retrieval

Boolean wifi;
CheckBox cB1;

The Thing is that code isn't working I am getting the value from the Toast When changing the data type but i really need to check the Checkbox again after getting the "ture" value from Firestore...
Looking forward to a good reply

```
DocumentReference dc = firebaseFirestore.collection("Hostel Admin").document(var);
        dc.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {



                wifi = Boolean.valueOf(value.getString("Wifi"));
                if (wifi.equals("true")) {
                    cB1.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    cB1.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a document's field called wifi in Firestore using Java, you can run the following code:

```
DocumentReference dc = firebaseFirestore.collection("Hostel Admin").document(var);
dc.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                      @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
      System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
      return;
    }
    // IF the document exists
    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
      System.out.println("Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
      
      // Get the wifi field of the document
      String document_wifi = snapshot.getString("wifi");
      // Convert the value to boolean
      Boolean wifi1 = Boolean.valueOf(document_wifi);
      boolean wifi = wifi1.booleanValue();
      // Or you can use the boolean primitive type (Uncomment the following line if you want boolean primitive type)
      // boolean wifi = Boolean.parseBoolean(document_wifi);

      // Then check if the boolean wifi contains the value true or false
      if (wifi) {
         cB1.setChecked(true);
      } else {
         cB1.setChecked(false);
      }
    } else {
      System.out.print("Current data: null");
    }
  }
});
```

Please have a look into the following [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Your code is not working because you are trying to check what contains a boolean variable with [.equals()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-equals) method which is to compare Strings.

Please note there is a difference between Boolean and boolean types in Java:

```
    Boolean boolean1 = Boolean.valueOf("true");
    boolean boolean2 = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

- Boolean: The Boolean class wraps a value of the primitive type boolean in an object. An object of type Boolean contains a single field whose type is boolean.
- boolean: no instance is needed, you use the primitive type.

So if you use Boolean.valueof(str) method, it will return you a Boolean object and to see what it contains you will need to use booleanValue() method of the Boolean class as per Official Documentation [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html).

So if you want to convert from String to a boolean, you can use the primitive class with the method parseBoolean(str)